What is the effect of memories vanishing?
Spoilers for the end of Nier Reincarnation:

 After completing the last chapter of Nier Reincarnation and restarting the game, a notice appears saying "Fio (The Girl of Light) has been reborn, causing her memories to vanish from The Cage." Despite this, I'm still able equip Fio in my loadout.

Are there any gameplay effects to this event happening? Did I lose access to anything?
